# HABTM selection seemingly ignores joinTable

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

**UPDATE #2 -- SOLUTION FOUND:**
Turns out my use of this lookup:

```
$this->User->Group->find(....)
```

was not what I needed. To pull out a user's groups I needed to use:

```
$this->User->find('all',array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $user_id)));
```

**< /UPDATE #2>< PROBLEM>**

I'm attempting to do a HABTM relationship between a `Users` table and `Groups` table. The problem is, that I when I issue this call:

```
$this->User->Group->find('list');
```

The query that is issued is:

```
SELECT [Group].[id] AS [Group__id], [Group].[name] AS [Group__name] FROM [groups] AS [Group] WHERE 1 = 1
```

I can only assume at this point that I have defined my relationship wrong as I would expect behavior to use the `groups_users` table that is defined on the database as per convention. My relationships:

```
class User extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'User';
        //...snip...
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className'             => 'Group',
            'foreignKey'            => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id',
            'joinTable'             => 'groups_users',
            'unique'                => true,
        )
    );
        //...snip...
}

class Group extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Group';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array ( 'User' => array(
        'className'             => 'User',
        'foreignKey'            => 'group_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinTable'             => 'groups_users',
        'unique'                => true,
    ));
}
```

Is my understanding of HABTM wrong? How would I implement this Many to Many relationship where I can use CakePHP to query the `groups_users` table such that a list of groups the currently authenticated user is associated with is returned?

**UPDATE**

After applying the change suggested by *ndm* I still receive a large array return (Too big to post) which returns all groups and then a `'User'` element if the user has membership to that group. I looked at the query CakePHP uses again:

```
SELECT 
    [User].[id] AS [User__id], 
    [User].[username] AS [User__username], 
    [User].[password] AS [User__password], 
    [User].[email] AS [User__email], CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 
    [User].[created], 20) AS [User__created], CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 
    [User].[modified], 20) AS [User__modified], 
    [User].[full_name] AS [User__full_name], 
    [User].[site] AS [User__site], 
    [GroupsUser].[user_id] AS [GroupsUser__user_id], 
    [GroupsUser].[group_id] AS  [GroupsUser__group_id], 
    [GroupsUser].[id] AS [GroupsUser__id] 
FROM 
    [users] AS [User] JOIN 
        [groups_users] AS [GroupsUser] ON (
        [GroupsUser].[group_id] IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND 
        [GroupsUser].[user_id] = [User].[id]
    )
```

Is there an easy way to refine that such that I only receive the group ids & names for the entries I have membership to? I was thinking of using:

```
array('conditions'=>array('GroupsUser.user_id'=>$user_id))
```

...but I receive an sql error on the groups table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Group].[name] AS [Group__name], CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [Group].[created], 20) AS [Group__created], CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), [Group].[modified], 20) AS [Group__modified], [Group].[id] AS [Group__id] FROM [groups] AS [Group] WHERE [GroupsUser].[user_id] = 36 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
```

Comment: Just FYI, the only 2 lines of code you need (one in each model) are: `public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');` and `public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Group');`  All others are redundant, as they are already the default values.

Comment: I've changed my models. Thanks @Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just misunderstood what the `list` find type is ment to do.

The query is totally fine, the `list` find type is used for retreiving a list of records of a single model only, where the models [primary key](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey) is used as index, and the [display field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#model-displayfield) as value.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

Comment: Ah sorry. `'list'` was only the latest version as I was begining to attempt a brute-force solution before asking this question. Using the `'all'` param I get a massive list that again contains all the available groups but only nests a `'User'` portion to the ones my user has membership for. Is this normal? Can I refine the search somehow? Using `fields` or `conditions` seems to break the query giving errors on my usage of `array(conditions=>array('User.username'=>$user_id))`

Comment: Correction. I think I've fixed it. I changed my `find` to: `$this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$user_id)));` The additional $this->user->`group` caused that lookup issue. Thank you!